# hook_field_formatter_view not being called

Tags: theming

I cannot for the life of my figure out why `cc_byline_author_field_formatter_view` is not being called here. `hook_field_formatter_info` works as I can select the formatter for my field. Cache clear, module name change, module disable and re-enable have not helped.

Thanks for having a look.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function cc_byline_author_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    'cc_byline_author_author_replace' => array(
      'label' => t('Byline Author Replacement'),
      'field types' => array('text'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function cc_byline_author_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  die;
  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whelp, there goes an hour.

Turns out I was configuring the "Default" Display rather than the "Full Content" Display.